# GeoServer Data Download Problem

Tags: geoserver, wms

My GeoServer cannot download any layer data in any format, I only got `503 service unavaible` error.
This is my geoserver log:

```
2021-09-21 17:05:16,057 INFO [geoserver.wms] - 
Request: getCapabilities
    BaseUrl = http://*****.*****.gov.tr:80/geoserver/
    Get = false
    Namespace = cem
    RawKvp = {REQUEST=GetCapabilities, SERVICE=WMS}
    Request = GetCapabilities
    RequestCharset = null
    UpdateSequence = null
    Version = 1.3.0
2021-09-21 17:07:39,401 INFO [geoserver.wms] - 
Request: getServiceInfo
2021-09-21 17:07:39,416 INFO [geoserver.wms] - 
Request: getCapabilities
    BaseUrl = http://*******.****.gov.tr:80/geoserver/
    Get = false
    Namespace = su_erozyonu
    RawKvp = {REQUEST=GetCapabilities, SERVICE=WMS}
    Request = GetCapabilities
    RequestCharset = null
    UpdateSequence = null
    Version = 1.3.0
2021-09-21 17:17:10,238 INFO [geoserver.wms] - 
Request: getServiceInfo
2021-09-21 17:17:10,253 INFO [geoserver.wms] - 
Request: getLegendGraphic
    BaseUrl = http://******.*****.gov.tr:80/geoserver/
    Env = {}
    Exceptions = SE_XML
    FeatureType = null
    Format = image/png
    Get = false
    Height = 20
    Kvp = {REQUEST=GetLegendGraphic, FORMAT=image/png, SERVICE=WMS, SESSION=oY1Rm x224Uh8CGs8uHOkw==, WIDTH=20, LAYER=cem:erozyon, HEIGHT=20}
    Layers = [SimpleFeatureTypeImpl http://www.opengis.net/gml:GridCoverage identified extends Feature(geom:geom,grid:grid,params:params)]
    LegendOptions = {}
    Legends = [LegendRequest [layer=cem:erozyon, name=http://www.opengis.net/gml:GridCoverage styleName=null, title=Türkiye Erozyon Risk Haritası, legendInfo=null]]
    Locale = null
    RawKvp = {REQUEST=GetLegendGraphic, FORMAT=image/png, SERVICE=WMS, SESSION=oY1Rm x224Uh8CGs8uHOkw==, WIDTH=20, LAYER=cem:erozyon, HEIGHT=20}
    Request = GetLegendGraphic
    RequestCharset = null
    Rules = [null]
    Scale = -1.0
    Strict = true
    Styles = [StyleImpl[ name=erozyon]]
    Transparent = false
    Version = 1.1.1
    Width = 20
    Wms = org.geoserver.wms.WMS@ca4a7a

2021-09-21 17:40:26,384 INFO [geoserver.wms] - 
Request: getFeatureInfo
    BaseUrl = http://*****.*****.gov.tr:80/geoserver/
    Exceptions = application/vnd.ogc.se_xml
    FeatureCount = 1
    Get = false
    GetMapRequest = 
GetMap Request
 version: 1.1.1
 output format: image/png
 width height: 200,300
 bbox: SRSEnvelope[32.94615963176188 : 32.94615965176188, 39.91556076662981 : 39.91556078662981]
 layers: cem:ruzgar_erozyonu_haritasi
 styles: ruzgar_erozyonu2
    InfoFormat = application/json
    PropertyNames = null
    QueryLayers = [org.geoserver.wms.MapLayerInfo@bc2e4c54]
    RawKvp = {FORMAT=image/png, INFO_FORMAT=application/json, WIDTH=200, HEIGHT=300, LAYERS=cem:ruzgar_erozyonu_haritasi, REQUEST=GetFeatureInfo, SRS=EPSG:4326, BBOX=32.94615963176188,39.91556076662981,32.94615965176188,39.91556078662981, VERSION=1.1.1, X=100, Y=150, SERVICE=WMS, QUERY_LAYERS=cem:ruzgar_erozyonu_haritasi}
    Request = GetFeatureInfo
    RequestCharset = null
    Version = 1.1.1
    XPixel = 100
    YPixel = 150
2021-09-21 17:40:26,384 INFO [wfs.json] - about to encode JSON
2021-09-21 17:40:26,556 INFO [geoserver.wms] - 
Request: getServiceInfo
2021-09-21 17:40:26,649 INFO [geoserver.wms] - 
Request: getFeatureInfo
    BaseUrl = http://****.****.gov.tr:80/geoserver/
    Exceptions = application/vnd.ogc.se_xml
    FeatureCount = 1
    Get = false
    GetMapRequest = 
GetMap Request
 version: 1.1.1
 output format: image/png
 width height: 200,300
 bbox: SRSEnvelope[32.94615963176188 : 32.94615965176188, 39.91556076662981 : 39.91556078662981]
 layers: cem:su_erozyonu_haritasi
 styles: su_erozyonu
    InfoFormat = application/json
    PropertyNames = null
    QueryLayers = [org.geoserver.wms.MapLayerInfo@9dc2cdb3]
    RawKvp = {FORMAT=image/png, INFO_FORMAT=application/json, WIDTH=200, HEIGHT=300, LAYERS=cem:su_erozyonu_haritasi, REQUEST=GetFeatureInfo, SRS=EPSG:4326, BBOX=32.94615963176188,39.91556076662981,32.94615965176188,39.91556078662981, VERSION=1.1.1, X=100, Y=150, SERVICE=WMS, QUERY_LAYERS=cem:su_erozyonu_haritasi}
    Request = GetFeatureInfo
    RequestCharset = null
    Version = 1.1.1
    XPixel = 100
    YPixel = 150
2021-09-21 17:40:26,649 INFO [wfs.json] - about to encode JSON
```

---

I restarted Tomcat and now my site is not working any more. I took the geoserver debug mode and my log is:

```
2021-09-22 10:11:00,965 TRACE [ows.OWSHandlerMapping] - No handler mapping found for [/web/]
2021-09-22 10:11:00,965 DEBUG [geoserver.ows] - Could not a layer group named web
2021-09-22 10:11:00,965 TRACE [ows.OWSHandlerMapping] - No handler mapping found for [/web/]
2021-09-22 10:11:00,966 DEBUG [geoserver.ows] - Could not a layer group named web
2021-09-22 10:11:00,966 TRACE [ows.OWSHandlerMapping] - No handler mapping found for [/web/]
2021-09-22 10:11:00,966 DEBUG [geoserver.ows] - Could not a layer group named web
2021-09-22 10:11:00,966 TRACE [ows.OWSHandlerMapping] - No handler mapping found for [/web/]
2021-09-22 10:11:00,967 DEBUG [geoserver.filters] - Compressing output for mimetype: text/html; charset=UTF-8
2021-09-22 10:11:00,970 DEBUG [filter.GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter$1] - SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
2021-09-22 10:11:04,767 DEBUG [security.IncludeQueryStringAntPathRequestMatcher] - Checking match of request : 'Path: /web/wicket/bookmarkable/org.geoserver.web.admin.logpage, QueryString: null'; against '/web/**'
2021-09-22 10:11:04,767 DEBUG [security.IncludeQueryStringAntPathRequestMatcher] - Matched Path: /web/wicket/bookmarkable/org.geoserver.web.admin.logpage, QueryString: null with /web/**
2021-09-22 10:11:04,784 DEBUG [geoserver.ows] - Could not a layer group named web
2021-09-22 10:11:04,784 TRACE [ows.OWSHandlerMapping] - No handler mapping found for [/web/wicket/bookmarkable/org.geoserver.web.admin.LogPage]
2021-09-22 10:11:04,785 DEBUG [geoserver.ows] - Could not a layer group named web
2021-09-22 10:11:04,785 TRACE [ows.OWSHandlerMapping] - No handler mapping found for [/web/wicket/bookmarkable/org.geoserver.web.admin.LogPage]
2021-09-22 10:11:04,785 DEBUG [geoserver.ows] - Could not a layer group named web
2021-09-22 10:11:04,785 TRACE [ows.OWSHandlerMapping] - No handler mapping found for [/web/wicket/bookmarkable/org.geoserver.web.admin.LogPage]
2021-09-22 10:11:04,786 DEBUG [geoserver.ows] - Could not a layer group named web
2021-09-22 10:11:04,786 TRACE [ows.OWSHandlerMapping] - No handler mapping found for [/web/wicket/bookmarkable/org.geoserver.web.admin.LogPage]
2021-09-22 10:11:04,787 DEBUG [org.geoserver] - Thread 12917 locking in mode READ
2021-09-22 10:11:04,787 DEBUG [org.geoserver] - Thread 12917 got the lock in mode READ
2021-09-22 10:11:04,964 DEBUG [org.geoserver] - Thread 12917 locking in mode READ
2021-09-22 10:11:04,964 DEBUG [org.geoserver] - Thread 12917 releasing the lock in mode READ
2021-09-22 10:11:04,969 DEBUG [filter.GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter$1] - SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
2021-09-22 10:11:04,974 DEBUG [security.IncludeQueryStringAntPathRequestMatcher] - Checking match of request : 'Path: /web/wicket/bookmarkable/org.geoserver.web.admin.logpage, QueryString: 36'; against '/web/**'
2021-09-22 10:11:04,974 DEBUG [security.IncludeQueryStringAntPathRequestMatcher] - Matched Path: /web/wicket/bookmarkable/org.geoserver.web.admin.logpage, QueryString: 36 with /web/**
2021-09-22 10:11:04,991 DEBUG [geoserver.ows] - Could not a layer group named web
2021-09-22 10:11:04,992 TRACE [ows.OWSHandlerMapping] - No handler mapping found for [/web/wicket/bookmarkable/org.geoserver.web.admin.LogPage]
2021-09-22 10:11:04,992 DEBUG [geoserver.ows] - Could not a layer group named web
2021-09-22 10:11:04,992 TRACE [ows.OWSHandlerMapping] - No handler mapping found for [/web/wicket/bookmarkable/org.geoserver.web.admin.LogPage]
2021-09-22 10:11:04,992 DEBUG [geoserver.ows] - Could not a layer group named web
2021-09-22 10:11:04,993 TRACE [ows.OWSHandlerMapping] - No handler mapping found for [/web/wicket/bookmarkable/org.geoserver.web.admin.LogPage]
2021-09-22 10:11:04,993 DEBUG [geoserver.ows] - Could not a layer group named web
2021-09-22 10:11:04,993 TRACE [ows.OWSHandlerMapping] - No handler mapping found for [/web/wicket/bookmarkable/org.geoserver.web.admin.LogPage]
2021-09-22 10:11:04,994 DEBUG [geoserver.filters] - Compressing output for mimetype: text/html; charset=UTF-8
2021-09-22 10:11:04,999 DEBUG [filter.GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter$1] - SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
2021-09-22 10:11:06,672 DEBUG [security.IncludeQueryStringAntPathRequestMatcher] - Checking match of request : 'Path: /web/wicket/bookmarkable/org.geoserver.web.admin.logpage, QueryString: 36-1.IFormSubmitListener-form'; against '/web/**'
2021-09-22 10:11:06,673 DEBUG [security.IncludeQueryStringAntPathRequestMatcher] - Matched Path: /web/wicket/bookmarkable/org.geoserver.web.admin.logpage, QueryString: 36-1.IFormSubmitListener-form with /web/**
2021-09-22 10:11:06,689 DEBUG [geoserver.ows] - Could not a layer group named web
2021-09-22 10:11:06,689 TRACE [ows.OWSHandlerMapping] - No handler mapping found for [/web/wicket/bookmarkable/org.geoserver.web.admin.LogPage]
2021-09-22 10:11:06,689 DEBUG [geoserver.ows] - Could not a layer group named web
2021-09-22 10:11:06,689 TRACE [ows.OWSHandlerMapping] - No handler mapping found for [/web/wicket/bookmarkable/org.geoserver.web.admin.LogPage]
2021-09-22 10:11:06,690 DEBUG [geoserver.ows] - Could not a layer group named web
2021-09-22 10:11:06,690 TRACE [ows.OWSHandlerMapping] - No handler mapping found for [/web/wicket/bookmarkable/org.geoserver.web.admin.LogPage]
2021-09-22 10:11:06,690 DEBUG [geoserver.ows] - Could not a layer group named web
2021-09-22 10:11:06,690 TRACE [ows.OWSHandlerMapping] - No handler mapping found for [/web/wicket/bookmarkable/org.geoserver.web.admin.LogPage]
2021-09-22 10:11:06,691 DEBUG [org.geoserver] - Thread 12832 locking in mode READ
2021-09-22 10:11:06,692 DEBUG [org.geoserver] - Thread 12832 got the lock in mode READ
2021-09-22 10:11:06,694 DEBUG [org.geoserver] - Thread 12832 locking in mode READ
2021-09-22 10:11:06,694 DEBUG [org.geoserver] - Thread 12832 releasing the lock in mode READ
2021-09-22 10:11:06,699 DEBUG [filter.GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter$1] - SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
2021-09-22 10:11:06,704 DEBUG [security.IncludeQueryStringAntPathRequestMatcher] - Checking match of request : 'Path: /web/wicket/bookmarkable/org.geoserver.web.admin.logpage, QueryString: lines=1000'; against '/web/**'
2021-09-22 10:11:06,704 DEBUG [security.IncludeQueryStringAntPathRequestMatcher] - Matched Path: /web/wicket/bookmarkable/org.geoserver.web.admin.logpage, QueryString: lines=1000 with /web/**
2021-09-22 10:11:06,722 DEBUG [geoserver.ows] - Could not a layer group named web
2021-09-22 10:11:06,723 TRACE [ows.OWSHandlerMapping] - No handler mapping found for [/web/wicket/bookmarkable/org.geoserver.web.admin.LogPage]
2021-09-22 10:11:06,723 DEBUG [geoserver.ows] - Could not a layer group named web
2021-09-22 10:11:06,723 TRACE [ows.OWSHandlerMapping] - No handler mapping found for [/web/wicket/bookmarkable/org.geoserver.web.admin.LogPage]
2021-09-22 10:11:06,723 DEBUG [geoserver.ows] - Could not a layer group named web
2021-09-22 10:11:06,724 TRACE [ows.OWSHandlerMapping] - No handler mapping found for [/web/wicket/bookmarkable/org.geoserver.web.admin.LogPage]
2021-09-22 10:11:06,724 DEBUG [geoserver.ows] - Could not a layer group named web
2021-09-22 10:11:06,724 TRACE [ows.OWSHandlerMapping] - No handler mapping found for [/web/wicket/bookmarkable/org.geoserver.web.admin.LogPage]
2021-09-22 10:11:06,725 DEBUG [org.geoserver] - Thread 12838 locking in mode READ
2021-09-22 10:11:06,726 DEBUG [org.geoserver] - Thread 12838 got the lock in mode READ
```

Comment: There is no error in this log, try investigating between geoserver and the calling client

Comment: does the ser4vice work locally, ie as localhost?

Comment: I took Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 503 (Service Unavailable) error on my site for all wms services, I checked wms services on geoserver couldn't find an error, I will check again.

Comment: logs can be set in to a verbose mode (debugging) https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/configuration/globalsettings.html

Comment: There is still no error in your log